# how do i swipe to delete from a web service

Tags: objective-c, web-services, uitableview

i have a web service to delete a record from my db
`http://url.com/delete/recordID`

how would i go about implementing a swipe to delete on the tableview cell to call this url.

i know it has to be done in

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {

    }
}
```

but I'm not sure how to write it

Comment: How you populate your table, and what one cell contains of data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that you have array with some data. I propose you to use AFNetworking framework for communication with server.

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

        if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        Record *record = self.recordsArray[indexPath.row];
        AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];


                [manager DELETE:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://url.com/delete/%@", record.recordId] parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation * operation, id responseObject) {
            }
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
                    }];
        }
```